# Repeating an operation x times and catch the results in a vector

Tags: r

If I have an operation including randomness (lets call it `operation_with_randomness(number)`) and I want it to run x times

```
> b <- rep(operation_with_randomness(number), x)
```

I get

```
> b 
1.5472491 1.5472491 1.5472491 1.5472491 1.5472491 1.5472491 ...
```

Is there any smart way (e.g. not a loop structure) to run the `operation_with_randomness(number)` each time to get a *b* vector which holds values from *x* separate runs?

Comment: The reason your code does not work is because `operation_with_randomness` will only be executed once, then `rep` will repeat the result x times.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably replicate() will meet:

```
> z <- replicate(10, runif(1))
> z
 [1] 0.762778299 0.541601960 0.654238258 0.026323048 0.532011084 0.905059722 0.328891040 0.297307167 0.004157573 0.507231966
```